# Android device as touchpad

Tags: android, bluetooth, touch, mouse

So I'm sitting with a problem, it's seem trivial and should be easy to solve, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do it

My goal is use my android device as a touchpad connected through Bluetooth. It's somewhat working, but the it immediately moves the pointer to the point I touched, instead of only moving when I move my finger across the screen.

```
        touchpad.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                String xps = "X: "+(event.getX());
                String yps = "Y: "+(event.getY());


                cmd  = xps + " " + yps + "\n";                  
                moveCursor(cmd);

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

private void moveCursor(String command)
{

        byte[] cmd = command.getBytes();
        try 
        {
            OPS.write(cmd);
        }
        catch (IOException e){

            Log.e("Command error", command + " could not be executed");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the server side I simply use a Robot to emulate the mouse by calling robot.MouseMove(x,y)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java developer, nor have I used Robot before so I can't provide you with usable code examples...but I have written some draggable code using both mouse events and touch events. What I believe you are missing is a starting point, and then adding the delta (change) to the starting point. It seems to me with your code example that you could get the starting point (and store it in a variable) from the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN you have empty now, and then get the delta at the top of your MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE section. From there you would use your starting point, and add the delta in your move event.